# Execute a PHP cron every 5 minutes but put a function to sleep to run after 15 minutes

Tags: php, cron, command-line-interface

I have a PHP script that run on cron every 5 minutes.

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/html/processMail.php
```

Inside the script there is a function that I want to execute every 15 minutes, so that function will be in sleep mode but the rest of the script will be process every 5 minutes.

does this crazy idea will work and how?

Comment: It sounds like a hack to me? Could you explain the actual problem you're trying to solve, not the solution you've come up with? My first thought was that this might better be split between a 5 min cron and a separate 15m cron.

Comment: Hi Nanne. Thanks for the suggestion. I thought there should be an easy way to make a function sleep and run for a specific time rather than setting up a new cron.

Comment: But the question does not make sense as it is :). If you start a script every 5 minutes that starts a function that should run every 15 minutes, you'd get a lot of calls soon!. Or did you mean you want to run a script every 5 minutes, but skip a certain function 2 out of 3 times? (so not on 5 and 10, but on 15, and then not on 20 and 25, but on 30)? Because that is not "sleep", that would just be checking if it should run. that's doable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does this crazy idea will work and how?

No it won't. The each 15 minute function would - even if you manage to wait 15 minutes - be executed each 5 minutes - so effectively the 15 minutes function is executed each 5 minutes. Instead create a second script that is executed every 15 minutes or add a parameter:

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/html/processMail.php --mins=5
*/15 * * * * /var/www/html/processMail.php --mins=15
```

Then use the functionality to parse [commandline-parameters in PHP](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.argv.php) (and [`getopt`](http://php.net/getopt)) to process accordingly. See as well [the section about commandline usage in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/features.commandline.php).

Comment: Thanks for clarification that this idea won't work but to create a second script to execute every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You could save an iterator in a file or a database and increment it after every run, this way you can only run it once in 3 times the script runs.

However, a much better solution would simply be to write another script and run it every 15 minutes.